# kotlin -- can I rewrite this map access to get rid of the ``!!``?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, null, nullable

Let's say I have a

```
enum class ConceptualPosition{
    A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,
    B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,
    C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8
}
```

And I now want to construct a Graph where every position has a Node.

```
import [...].domain.model.base.ConceptualPosition
import [...].domain.model.base.ConceptualPosition.*
import [...].domain.model.base.Node
import [...].domain.model.base.Node.MovableDirection.*

class MyGraph:Graph{
    private val internalPositions = mutableMapOf<ConceptualPosition, Node>()
    override val position by lazy {internalPositions.toMap().withDefault {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("position '$it' does not exist")
    }}

    init{
        //create nodes for all positions
        ConceptualPosition.values().forEach { internalPositions[it] = Node(it) }

        //now build graph
        position[A1]!!.connectBothWaysWith(position[A2]!!,RIGHT)
        position[A2]!!.connectBothWaysWith(position[A3]!!,RIGHT)
        [...]

    }
}
```

since I have a `withDefault` that immediately throws an exception and since Kotlin correctly infers the type of `position` to be `Map<ConceptualPosition,Node>`, I think I can be fairly sure that if a lookup does not fail, I get a non-null value out of it.

Kotlin apparently cannot safely infer that.

Can I refactor this (in a reasonable way) to get rid of the `!!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Map.getValue`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html) instead of `get`:

```
position.getValue(A1).connectBothWaysWith(position.getValue(A2),RIGHT)
```

Alternately, you could define your own version of `withDefault` with a more precise return type (the Kotlin standard library [makes the equivalent private](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.3.0/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kt)):

```
class MapWithDefault<K, V>(val map: Map<K, V>, val default: (K) -> V) : Map<K, V> by map {
    override fun get(key: K): V = map[key] ?: default(key)
}

fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.withDefault(default: (K) -> V) = MapWithDefault(this, default)
```

Comment: Thank you! Small edit suggestion: You need to extend a concrete map implementation. E.g. ``:HashMap<K,V>(map)`` instead of ``:Map<K,V> by map``. Otherwise, you seem to get errors like ``no set method providing array access``.

Comment: There's no set method because I assumed you wanted an immutable map from `toMap()` in your code :) Otherwise, changing both `: Map` to `: MutableMap` is a better idea than extending `HashMap`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed when my JUnit tests started to strangely fail, all of a sudden. XD
Problem is, I have both, mutable *and* immutable maps with defaults. (And I'd like to keep my immutable maps immutable.) Duplicating the code for ``MutableMap`` worked. But I wonder if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't think so, unfortunately. It's duplicated in the standard library too. You'll run into similar trouble if/when you want to extend arrays: `Array<T>`, `IntArray`, etc. :(